# Can I change the value of parameter between two execution in unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

My main script executes cases twice between 10 seconds in the same directory. I change the value of self.a in the test case before the second execution. However, I find that the value written in the log file has not changed. I want to ask why and how can I solve this.

My main script:

```
tests = unittest.TestLoader().discover('test_data',pattern="*.py")
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(tests)
time.sleep(10)

tests2 = unittest.TestLoader().discover('test_data',pattern="*.py")
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(tests2)
```

And my test case:

```
class test_mytest(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self) -> None:
    self.timer = time.strftime("%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(time.time()))
    self.a="11111"

def test_1_get_success(self):
    with open("result/debug.log","a") as f:
        f.write(str(self.timer)+"\n")
        f.write(self.a+"\n")
    f.close()

def tearDown(self) -> None:
    pass
```

Comment: If you change an instance variable in the first test, this does not change that variable in another instance of that test. Maybe you can explain what do you want to achieve in your real test.

Comment: In my project, the main script will generate test cases automatically. After the first execution, cases will be deleted and then generated again in the second execution. The two generated file names are the same but variables are different.

Comment: Ah, so you write a changed test to the same file. This may be a problem - as far as I remember, pytest caches the tests and will not re-read them if changnd in the same test run. Maybe you can add an increasing number to the test case instead.